# PuTTY SSH Tunneling not working on Linux

Tags: linux, ssh, putty, ssh-tunnel

I am running a server on Debian which has Webmin installed on there, which is not running the default port.

I've recently installed Linux Mint, replacing Windows.

When I had Windows I used PuTTY to port forward my Webmin port and everything worked on Windows using localhost:port.

Since coming over to Linux I installed PuTTY and setup my port forwarding again in the SSH section.

I login to my server and try to access my webmin through localhost:port and it just says connection refused in chrome?

I cannot think what has happened as this worked back on Windows.

I do have a local apache2 server running on Linux Mint, I thought that might be interfering but I stopped apache2 and still no luck.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Without any commands or errors it is hard to help.

Comment: I did read something about setting a proxy on chrome, but when I was on Windows I just connect via Putty/ ssh and could access my tunnel right away using localhost:portnumber with out any issues, what is different on Linux that I am missing? Is there anything I can do to test anything?

Comment: What port are you using?

Comment: I set a custom port for webmin of 5436, bare in mind everything worked when I was on Windows, I have not changed anything server side since. I can access my server, its just the tunneling that is not working.

Comment: Any idea? Im stuck now?

Comment: Try using 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost. Sometimes localhost is not resolved correctly. As Sander always wrote use something like `ssh -L 127.0.0.1:5436:127.0.0.1:Webmin_port user@Debian_server`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you now work with Linux Mint, I suggest that you use `ssh` on the command line and use the verbose mode to see if it print messages that relate to the tunnel. So try something along the lines of `ssh -L 5436:Debian_server:Webmin_port user@Debian_server -v`

Please report any messages that are related to making the tunnel. If all goes well, expect a message like this:
debug1: Local connections to LOCALHOST:5436 forwarded to remote address ...

Comment: Thanks, it works via command line SSH. I had to convert my .ppk key but everything works via ssh just not putty, I guess I will just ssh in over the terminal for now then.

Comment: Great. In the mean time, I've installed PuTTY on my linux machine as well (I'm using ArchLinux, installed it from the repository), and making a tunnel posed no problems. Although I prefer the command line interface for SSH, I'm kind of curious why PuTTY would not work. How did you install it?

Comment: Literally through the software store on Linux Mint.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a bit old, but I had the same issue when migrating putty sessions from windows to Fedora linux. The answer is quite simple. I put it here for the benefit of others with similar problems.

On linux (well on Fedora at least), a normal user cannot redirect local ports less than 1024 unless you use root user (or sudo I guess). Putty on linux uses the linux installed SSH as far as I can tell. Windows putty did its own thing I believe, or at least installed a windows ssh version that did not seem to have this limitation. I think the linux approach is probably the most secure, while the windows approach is for convenience.

So rather than run putty under sudo, I just redirected local ports above 1024 to the remote network.

So in the OP, you could redirect (say) 127.0.1.1:1080 -> debian_server:5436 for instance.

In my case (on windows) I used to redirect local 127.0.1.1:80->192.168.1.1:80 (to be able to operate the web interface of the router on the remote network. The putty session config (in registry) under windows was like so:

```
"PortForwardings"="4L127.0.1.1:80=192.168.1.1:80,"
```

On Fedora, the entry in the session config file became:

```
PortForwardings=4L127.0.1.1:1080=192.168.1.1:80
```

This can also be used for https by using local port (say) 1443 to remote port of 443.

On Linux, these can be setup in the conf file or the opening putty config gui.